# Xanthan Gum in sauce/gravy

Tags: low-carb, xanthan, keto

I'm making Salisbury Steak  (https://www.skinnytaste.com/skinny-salisbury-steak-) but would like to substitute xanthan gum for flour to reduce carbs AND use coconut or almond flour (and / or psyllium husk powder) instead of bread crumbs. Instead of 2 T. Flour how much xanthan gum should I use?  Can I use coconut/almond/psyllium husk powder instead of bread crumbs to hold the patty together?

Answer (score 3):

The flour in this recipe is for thickening the sauce.  You can use xanthan for this purpose, but in very small amounts...0.25 to 0.75% for a thin to medium running sauce.  As you increase the amount, xanthan will make your sauce take on an unpleasant, mucous-like texture.

This is most easily calculated in weight (and metric).  I'll have a go, and convert it back:

You have 2 cups of broth = about 480 grams + some other liquid.  I would suggest 500 grams is a reasonable estimate.   .25% of 500 grams = 1.25 grams of xanthan (start on the low end.  You can always add more).  There are about 4 grams in a teaspoon.  I would suggest 1/4 teaspoon of xanthan as a reasonable starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the information... I'll update this thread with the results

Comment: I used about 1/8 t. which thickened the sauce slightly. I added it to lukewarm beef broth and the powder clumped up and was lumpy. Using the back of the spoon smoothed out the lumps but I noticed later that some of the xanthan gum was on the spoon instead of in the gravy.  Next time I'll add a small amount of the liquid to the powder to try and avoid that problem. The xanthan gum created no noticeable change in flavor to the sauce which was very flavorful and I'm somewhat satisfied with my first experience with this ingredient.  I am looking forward to finding an opportunity to use it again.

Comment: Try adding the xanthan with a bit of salt or sugar to help blending well. It won't work with a liquid, I'm affraid.